# Consistent parsing of text for raw html output

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have some text input into a `textarea` that looks like the following:

```
Here's some text./r/n
/r/n
Here's some more text.
```

I'd like to render this upon display like so:

```
<p>Here's some text.</p>
<p>Here's some more text.</p>
```

Are there any modules in Node.js that take care of turning user-inputted text into raw HTML for display? Or should be I using some form of `replace`? If the latter, what's an appropriate regex?

Something like PHP's [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how complex you want the input text to be, but I would suggest [showdown](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown). It is a markdown to HTML converter written in javascript. Maybe a bit fancier than you're asking, but it should allow you to easily support markdown for input.

Answer (score 0):

In the given case this would do the trick (where `t` is the input ext and `n` is the `Node` to append to):

```
var a = t.split([\n\t\r]+) ;

for(var i = 0, p ; i < a.length ; i++) {
     p = document.createElement("p") ;
     if(!! window.ActiveXObject) p.innerText = a[i] ;
     else p.textContent = a[i] ;
     n.appendChild(p) ;
}
```

From your question It seems like you need a more general approach, however.

---

[Try it on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/etakiq/edit#preview)